# Help solve this error: Class CommerceLicenseEntityController does not exist

Tags: 7, commerce, entities, debugging

When I install the [Commerce Licence module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license), in D7, I get this error. I think it might have to do with my Drupal installation, I'm not sure.
What steps can I take to find out what causes this?

The whole warning texts is (2 warnings):

```
Warning: class_implements(): Class CommerceLicenseEntityController does not exist and could not be loaded in entity_entity_info_alter() (line 1480 of /data/disk/o1/distro/002/drupal-7.54.2-dev/sites/testsite.com/modules/entity/entity.module).

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in entity_entity_info_alter() (line 1480 of /data/disk/o1/distro/002/drupal-7.54.2-dev/sites/testsite.com/modules/entity/entity.module).
```

[image]

Comment: If you clear the cache does this error go away?

Comment: @Kevin Actually the warnings only are visible directly after enabling the module. When navigating elsewhere, the warning are not visible. When I disable the module, and enable the module again, the warnins again reappear. Clearing cache has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The error I got was a bit different, so this may not work for you. My error was

```
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class CommerceLicenseFile does 
not exist' in [filepath]/entity_bundle_plugin.module:46
```

I disabled the Commerce License module and renabled it. I can now clear cache without error. Hope that works for you if you have not solved the problem.